# Place emphasis that "thanks/me too" is not permitted anywhere

Tags: feature-request, wording, protected-questions

The protected questions text says the following:

[image]

As it stands currently, it sounds as though it's been protected only on a case by case basis, and that "thanks" or "me too" posts by new users is acceptable elsewhere.  Could it be reworded to tell new users that it's not acceptable to post these types of thing, anywhere?

Comment: I guess you mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)?

Comment: @hjpotter92 you mean the thing no one reads?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Precisely!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It reads just fine to me. For this to be an issue, you'd have to have somebody land on the site, visit a protected question, *read the message* (unlikely), find *another* question, and post a "me too", all without reading any of the other more prominent stuff telling them *not* to do this.

The site rules clearly say not to do this. Why would you expect somebody to skip the site rules, but "obey" the tiny snippet of text on a very small subset of questions?

Specifically, just focusing the answer form gives you a huge popup message saying...

> ### Your Answer
>
> Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow!
>
> - Please be sure to *answer the question*. Provide details and share your research!
>
> But *avoid* …
>
> - Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
> - Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.
>
> To learn more, see our [tips on writing great answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well does it say specifically that HELP ME types of posts are unacceptable?  No.  While it seems obvious, if you don't lay it out flat to new members, they are not doing to do any thinking for themselves.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy "Asking for help" in the third paragraph doesn't tell the answerer not to use the answer to ask for help?